# how to open amcharts.com credit link in new tab

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, amcharts

I have put an iframe loading amcharts candle chart in my php website. Since Iam using codeigniter the chart file is located inside third party folder.

[image: iframe before]

As you can see there is text saying "JS chart by amCharts" on top left side of chart. but on clicking the credit link amchart.com home page opens in that iframe.

[image: iframe after]

Iam okay with linking back to their website but their website should not load within my view page. So I want to know how to open amcharts.com on new tab when user clicks on credit link in chart in my website.

Comment: Take a look at the [target attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target), you will want to use `target="_blank"`

Comment: @KorelK - What are you trying to imply? Removing the link without a license? We do monitor questions tagged with amcharts, you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the top level [`urlTarget`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#urlTarget) property to "_blank" to make the credits link open in a new tab.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  urlTarget: "_blank",
  // ...
});
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/56b7230859942fb06385468c6065bbd9?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

The above from xorspark works for amcharts 3. But for those using the new amchart 4, you would have to(in my case for a pie): and

```
 Series.slices.template.urlTarget ="_blank";
 Series.slices.template.url = "{url}";
```

which would open the URL specified in the JSON dataset in a new tab.
I'm not sure if you need

```
Series.dataFields.url = "url";
```

but i have it included

Comment: Not quite the same. The question was about the anchor target of v3's "JS chart by amCharts", it is the equivalent of the amCharts logo on the bottom left in v4. In v4, most chart objects have `url` and `urlTarget` properties to conveniently turn them into links.